# Azure Storage CPP & VCPKG

Tags: c++, vcpkg

Have a small C++ app to test some Azure Blob Storage features with in Visual Studio 2019.
Have followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-c-plus-plus-how-to-use-blobs) to install azure-storage-cpp sdk using vcpkg but when I try to run the app I get the following linker error:

> AzureConsoleApp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) private: void __cdecl
>   azure::storage::cloud_storage_account::initialize_default_endpoints(bool)"
>   (__imp_?initialize_default_endpoints@cloud_storage_account@storage@azure@@AEAAX_N@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: __cdecl
>   azure::storage::cloud_storage_account::cloud_storage_account(class
>   azure::storage::storage_credentials const &,bool)"
>   (??0cloud_storage_account@storage@azure@@QEAA@AEBVstorage_credentials@12@_N@Z)

vcpkg reports the following as installed:

> azure-storage-cpp:x64-windows-static               7.0.0
>   Microsoft Azure Storage Client SDK for C++ A cli...

I need to use the static release of azure-storage-cpp for the app hence the x64-windows-static.

From reading the vcpkg docs it's an install and forget type of tool with the tool itself stating:

> All MSBuild C++ projects can now #include any installed libraries.
>   Linking will be handled automatically. Installing new libraries will
>   make them instantly available.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to define #define _NO_WASTORAGE_API before including azure storage sdk headers and manually include all the necessary azure storage SDK reference libraries (xmllite.lib, bcrypt.lib, rpcrt4.lib, Crypt32.lib, Winhttp.lib) in the linker input.

Found my answer [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-cpp/issues/263).